# does qt come with gnu make?

Tags: windows, qt, makefile

I am trying to compile meshlab under windows. According to their instructions ([link](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Compiling_V122#Compiling))

> Using GCC (both under linux and using the mingw gcc provided with the free Qt distribution) 
>   you should just type, from the
>   devel/meshlab/src directory:
>
> ```
> qmake -recursive meshlabv12.pro
> make
> ```

the first line works. The second fails with

```
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

I *do* have qt installed (I am trying to run make under a qt shell). 
Why do they claim this step is supposed to work under mingw (which came with qt), while it doesn't in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `make.bat` should be in MINGW\bin containing simply

```
@echo off
mingw32-make %*
```